# How to draw a triangle with OpenGL in Racket

Tags: opengl, racket

I'm trying to get this triangle example from the [Racket OpenGL documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sgl/main.html#%28def._%28%28lib._sgl%2Fmain..rkt%29._gl-begin%29%29) working inside a simple GUI window, but I'm just seeing a black box. What am I missing to get something to show up?

```lisp
#lang racket

(require racket/gui/base
         sgl
         sgl/gl-vectors)

(define frame (new frame% [label "OpenGL"]))

(define (draw self dc)
  (send self
        with-gl-context
        (lambda ()
          (gl-begin 'triangles)
          (gl-vertex 1 2 3)
          (gl-vertex-v (gl-float-vector 1 2 3 4))
          (gl-end))))

(define canvas (new canvas%
                    [parent frame]
                    [min-width 500]
                    [min-height 500]
                    [style '(gl)]
                    [paint-callback draw]))

(send frame show #t)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code draws red triangle into canvas. You can replace code inside `draw-triangle` with that example code, but it seems that it only shows some naming conventions and actually does nothing.

```
#lang racket/base

(require racket/gui
         sgl)

(define (draw-triangle)
  (gl-begin 'triangles)
  (gl-color 1 0 0)
  (gl-vertex 0 0 0)
  (gl-vertex 0.75 0 0)
  (gl-vertex 0.75 0.75 0)
  (gl-end))

(define my-canvas%
  (class* canvas% ()
    (inherit with-gl-context swap-gl-buffers)
    (define/override (on-paint)
      (with-gl-context (lambda ()
                         (draw-triangle)
                         (swap-gl-buffers))))
    (super-instantiate () (style '(gl)))))

(define frame (new frame%
                 [label "OpenGL"]
                 [min-width 500]
                 [min-height 500]))

(define canvas (new my-canvas%
                    [parent frame]))

(send frame show #t)
```

Comment: Hey Martin, thanks for the answer! I was able to get this working but I had to add another line at the beginning of `draw-triangle`: `(gl-viewport 0 0 500 500)`